# What's Oracle implementation of the CLI Standard?

Tags: sql, oracle, clr

It is known that [CLR](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Language_Runtime) is Microsoft's implementation of the [CLI standard](http://www.ecma-international.org/publications/standards/Ecma-335.htm).
But what about Oracle or even Postgre??

Comment: CLR is Microsoft's standard.  No-one else uses it.  In the database world, CLI is 'Call Level Interface', as opposed to the Embedded SQL techniques, for example, and is exemplified by the ODBC and JDBC libraries.  It is almost wholly unrelated to CLR/CLI (except tangentially; CLR/CLI might use a CLI to access a DBMS).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are no implementations from Oracle or PostgreSQL. As far as I am aware, there is currently only one implementation besides the one from Microsoft: [Mono](http://www.mono-project.com/Main_Page).

I don't actually understand why you think Oracle and PostgreSQL could have one. Those companies create databases. The CLI standard doesn't really have anything to do with databases.

Comment: So, It is not possible to create objects in one language and use it in other for example?

Comment: @cMinor: You are mixing everything here. Oracle and PostgreSQL aren't *languages*. CLI / CLR is not a *database*. And you can create objects in one language and use it in another, as long as both languages are based on the CLR.

Comment: What I would like to do is to have the layer of CLI as SQL Server has, so I can use multiple languages to create UDF's and then load those in the DBMS

Comment: @cMinor: In Oracle you can use Java to create objects etc. inside the database.

Comment: Conceptually, SQL Server allows you to build classes in .Net and call them 'natively' from within SQL Server. Oracle allows you to build classes in Java and call them natively from PL/SQL.

Answer (score 1):

> But what about Oracle or even Postgre??

There isn't one, as far as I'm aware. The closest Oracle has is Java (which isn't in any way a CLI implementation, but the CLI and Java are at least passingly similar). As for "Postgre" by which I assume you mean PostgreSQL - why would you *expect* them to have an implementation?

You understand that the CLI is effectively a VM specification, *not* a database, right?

Comment: Yeah, as I commented I want to create objects at this layer level and then deploy them inside the DBMS. I have done this effectivelty on SLQ Server, so I was wondering how to do that on Oracle or PostreSQL

Comment: @cMinor: You wouldn't.  Well, Oracle might let you put some Java in the DB, i dunno.  But integration with .NET is not very common outside of SQL Server.  PostgreSQL has an API you can use to write C modules for it, and i dunno what Oracle has, but if anything, it'll involve C or Java.